# Windows 7 installation on Samsung M.2 recognises using driver fails on first reboot

Tags: windows-7, m.2

I am attempting to install Windows 7 on a Samsung M.2 SSD. I ran into the same problem that everyone else seems to get at the start where the M.2 isn't showing up as an available drive to select as an installation disc. I searched for a while and was able to get the M.2 drivers, copy to my installer USB and load the drivers to see the M.2. Windows installation starts, copies files but on the first reboot it tries to start Windows and fails. It says Windows failed to start. Status 0xc0000225. It seems to me like the Window first time boot up process only reads the M.2 and then can't see the drive for the actual start up part. All of my research keeps returning results for the Load Driver problem that I was able to get around with the M.2 driver. Is this a problem with the M.2 or could this be a problem with my installation media? It's Windows 7 Home Premium that I am trying to install and the board is a Z170 Pro Gaming. Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the most part, Windows 7 will not (in standard operation) recognise a Samsung M.2 SSD past the boot loader. This means that any installation will run into resolvable issues. This is not possible. Weeks of research and diagnostics have brought me to this conclusion. If you can provide anything contrary I will remove this answer - however it seems to be the only definitive answer to date.

Comment: Winaero offers a possible solution. No idea if it works. https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-install-windows-7-on-a-pci-express-nvme-ssd/